# Get value from object in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
let script_type = {'vpl_run.sh':0,'vpl_debug.sh':1,'vpl_evaluate.sh':2,'vpl_evaluate.cases':2};
let list = ['vpl_run.sh','vpl_debug.sh', 'vpl_evaluate.sh', 'vpl_evaluate.cases'];
for (let i = 0, len = list.length; i < len; i++) {
    let fileName = list[i];
    console.log(script_type.fileName);
}
```

Always getting undefined in console log

**Note** : variable fileName has value as "vpl_run.sh" with dot (.)
what exactly I need is

```
    0
    1
    2
    2
```

Comment: Just do script_type[fileName]

Comment: You are accessing your dictionary data as if it was a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `console.log(script_type.fileName);`, do:

`console.log(script_type[fileName]);`.

Answer (score 1):

This is trivial in JS.

Just do `script_type[fileName]` and you have it.